# RSA and OAEP: Choosing or not choosing the Hash Algorithm?

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am implementing an asymmetrical encryption system:

```
''' <summary>
''' A facade for a data asymmetrical encryption algorithm relying on a pair of public and private keys.
''' </summary>
Public Interface IAsymEncrypter

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The public key to rely upon for encrypting data. Under XML format.
    ''' </summary>
    ReadOnly Property PublicKeyXml As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The private key to rely upon for decrypting data. Under XML format.
    ''' <para>Also contains the public key.</para>
    ''' </summary>
    ReadOnly Property PrivateKeyXml As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Encrypts data, using a public key.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Data">The data to encrypt.</param>
    Function Encrypt(Data As Byte()) As Byte()

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Decrypts data, using a private key.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Cipher">The cipher to decrypt the data from.</param>
    Function Decrypt(Cipher As Byte()) As Byte()

End Interface
```

The implementation wraps an `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. The implementation of `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` requires a choice for padding. I have already researched and understand the following:

- OAEP padding should be prefered over PKCS.
- The weakness against collisions of the hash algorithm associated with OAEP is, to date, not of concern and should not be a decisive criterion.
- Relying on a shorter output hash allows encrypting larger strings.

I am looking for the best security practices, whilst keeping maintenance as low as possible. I have seen that `.Encrypt` has two [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt):

- `.Encrypt(Data as Byte(), fOAEP as Boolean) as Byte()`, where `fOAEP` should be set to `True` to rely on OAEP. I assume this means the hash algorithm is chosen automatically; upon which criteria, that I did not figure out.
- `.Encrypt(Date as Byte(), Padding as RsaEncryptionPadding) as Byte()`, where one can specify OAEP associated with SHA-1 to SHA512.

Two questions:

1. Is the padding mode stored alongside the encrypted message? That is, can I guess from an encrypted message which padding mode to use to decrypt it?
2. If no, then I guess I am better off choosing the mode myself, in which case I would like to know if there are other considerations I should take into account?

Comment: `RSACryptoServiceProvider` only supports OAEP-SHA1, because the Windows CAPI library only supports OAEP-SHA1. Encrypting with any other OAEP will throw an exception: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsacryptoserviceprovider.cs,b3da00366a3aa47d

Comment: I just realized that.. ! So now I'm on my way to implement via Cng..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume this means the hash algorithm is chosen automatically; upon which criteria, that I did not figure out.

Unfortunately the old Microsoft API's are terribly underspecified (or rather underdocumented). This is not the only place where the algorithm or encoding method cannot be found. SHA-1 is the default in the standard, so it is probably used if you don't specify it (also for backwards compatibility).

---

> Q1: Is the padding mode stored alongside the encrypted message? That is, can I guess from an encrypted message which padding mode to use to decrypt it?

No, and even if it was, you shouldn't use it. RSA PKCS#1 specifies that you should pre-determine the configuration parameters. Besides that, you'd give a slight advantage to an attacker if you'd allow a change without verifying that choice first.

---

> Q2: If no, then I guess I am better off choosing the mode myself, in which case I would like to know if there are other considerations I should take into account?

SHA-1 is the default in the standard, SHA-256 might be used as it is both relatively fast and doesn't have any attacks.  It is also accelerated on the latest CPU's. Disadvantage: it's still the slowest hash on 64 bit machines without that acceleration (but, compared to RSA, it probably won't be that noticeable in practice). SHA-512 is both very fast and secure, although the security margin really doesn't matter much for this specific purpose.

If there are legacy concerns I'd just go with SHA-1 - in this setting SHA-1 must be terribly broken to be of concern. Otherwise SHA-256 makes more sense as it is *considerably* more secure.

---

Please do use the extended method so that other developers do not have to scratch their head as you're doing now. Plenty of questions here where people cannot replicate the algorithm in a different runtime. If you specify the configuration parameters clearly then you remove a lot of uncertainty.

Microsoft doesn't stand alone w.r.t. bad API documentation (although they do excel in it, I must say). I'm largely against using defaults for cryptography, if you have to document it yourself you might as well specify the configuration parameters in code.

---

And while we're discussing hiding essential details, aren't you afraid that you're hiding all the details in your Facade class? Generally these kind of classes are only a thin layer around the Microsoft specified API, and they hide exactly the details you don't want to hide. If they are used inside multiple projects it may be next to impossible to change them if you make any mistake.

Generally these kind of classes are created just to *wrap the knowledge of the developer* rather than having an application specific purpose. It's fine to write them for practicing purposes, but I'd not use them in your regular code base. Instead, write classes *for specific use cases*.

---

Generally you'd use hybrid cryptography and encrypt a random AES key if you're concerned that your message doesn't fit in a single block of RSA. Other runtimes then may use raw RSA to implement RSA-KEM but that's probably not a good idea in a Microsoft / .NET environment where you do always need to pad.

Comment: Thanks Maarten! The purpose of this class is to be more friendly to the developers, by (i) abstracting the security considerations (the facade should not allow any non-secure configurations, hence my questions here), and (ii) abstracting the handling of the encryption process itself. In other words, the developer who produces code which consumes the facade should not have to worry about what technology is being used, they have a black box and trust the setup the Crypto guys have made.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the thing I'm trying to warn you against. Use it as an example, but don't litter your product will ill maintained wrappers. Better to just create a code sample for them and review their code. In the worst case, they might learn something. Where's your upgrade path? That is available for a full fledged protocol, but not for an algorithm.

Comment: It is an interface so that various implementations, with different settings, can be relied upon for each specific case. If we make a security mistake or an algo becomes deprecated, we just have to update the implementation, easy no?

Comment: Indeed, that's not easy, given that you probably need to handle stuff that was encrypted way back. What kind of interface are you implementing that the experts at Microsoft could not come up with? What if your messages grow too big? What if you  need to switch to SHA-3? What if you need to change the implementation or worse, interface for **one specific project**?

Comment: "What kind of interface are you implementing": The one in my question :) So the implementations of this interface deal with the crypto problem, whilst the object consuming that interface deals with the rest. #SeparationOfConstraints?

Comment: I raise you tight coupling and the upgrade resistance. Separation of constraints is fine, but do it per project and think of an upgrade path (e.g. version identifier for a scheme). When I started out with crypto 20 years ago, I started by writing wrapper classes (encouraged by the experienced colleagues). Note that *I've been there*! Right, enough of it, the warning has been issued, which path you take is up to you...

Comment: We have an `IAsymEncrypter`, an `ISymEncrypter`, and an `ISignatory` interfaces, which all follow the same principles and are consummed the same way. For example, if I want to validate a license key: I have an object with a MachineGuid+ExpirationDate+Signature. Then I call `ISignatory.Verify(Data, Signature) as Boolean` and my class focuses on building `Data` from `MachineGuid` and `ExpirationDate`, not actually doing the signature verification, which is a separate matter. Also makes unit testing easier.

Comment: I would like to understand where your concern is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207376/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-ama).